# cannot read from softwareserial

Tags: softwareserial

I am able to use AT command from the Serial monitor however when I run the following code nothing is sent or received from the ESP8266. Can someone advise what could be the problem.

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>;

SoftwareSerial esp8266(0,1); // make RX Arduino line is pin 2, make TX Arduino line is pin 3.
                            // This means that you need to connect the TX line from the esp to the Arduino's pin 2
                             // and the RX line from the esp to the Arduino's pin 3
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  esp8266.begin(9600); // your esp's baud rate might be different
}

void loop()
{
 if(esp8266.available()) // check if the esp is sending a message 
  {
    while(esp8266.available())
    {
      // The esp has data so display its output to the serial window 
      char c = esp8266.read(); // read the next character.
      Serial.write(c);
    }  
  }


  if(Serial.available())
  {
    // the following delay is required because otherwise the arduino will read the first letter of the command but not the rest
    // In other words without the delay if you use AT+RST, for example, the Arduino will read the letter A send it, then read the rest and send it
    // but we want to send everything at the same time.
    delay(1000); 

    String command="";

    while(Serial.available()) // read the command character by character
    {
        // read one character
     command+=(char)Serial.read();
    }
    esp8266.println(command); // send the read character to the esp8266
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SoftwareSerial esp8266(0,1)
```

You can't use pins 0 and 1 for software serial since they are the hardware serial `Serial` than you use for communication with the PC.

Pick two other pins to use.